# Do I need to clear Thread.CurrentPrincipal?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

When user is connecting to my webservice I will set the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`(messageinspector) with my custom context and this can then be used thou out the entire solution.

The question is if this `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` needs to be set to null or is this only living during the current call?

It does seem to only last for the current call but Im not sure if that just a coincident?

BestRegards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This property represents your current security login and therefore should probably not be set to null unless you have a particular need to do so.  There are a number of situations where that would be appropriate (online banking, for example), but otherwise you will probably need it to continue accessing the resources you need to access.

Further reading at the MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No its not coincidental, i have found the same when your call finishes the current thread finishes and you no longer have the identity.